# JavaScript: setAttribute function is failing

Tags: javascript

I have slightly modified the code here
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_getelementsbyname_loop

**From:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Cats:  <input name="animal" type="checkbox" value="Cats">
Dogs:  <input name="animal" type="checkbox" value="Dogs">

<p>Click the button to check all checkboxes that have a name attribute with the value "animal".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("animal");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
            x[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**To:**
i.e. I want to change the value of value's attribute.

```
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
        x[i].setAttribute("value", "camels");
    }
}
```

It didn't change nothing, but What wrong am I doing?

**Edit: Requirement is to change the property in DOM not HTML.**

[image]

Comment: You can shorten it to `x[i].value = "camels";`. BTW, `setAttribute` should work too, did you change anything else by any chance?

Comment: you are right, it worked for me, but `setAttribute` didnt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looks to be doing what is expected](https://codepen.io/pabs123/pen/BGqvYy). The `value` attribute changes to camels for every single checkbox.

If what you're trying to do is change the TEXT beside the checkbox, you'll need to wrap it in its own element (likely a `p`) and change the `text` to be camel. Changing the `value` will only change the actual data value which that checkbox corresponds to.

Comment: When I do `webElement.getAtrribute("value")`; it will be some value. Same value I want to change using Javascriptexecutor, but what it is doing is change `value` in HTML. I have added picture for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is doing what you want, you just can't see it.  You are changing the value of the input, not the actual text "Dogs:", so what you end up with is:

```
Cats:  <input name="animal" type="checkbox" value="camels">
Dogs:  <input name="animal" type="checkbox" value="camels">
```